# Could someone explain what "process.argv" means in node.js please?

Tags: node.js

I'm currently learning node.js, and I was just curious what that meant, I am learning and could you tell me why this code does what it does:

```
var result = 0;

  for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++){
    result += Number(process.argv[i]);
}
  console.log(result);
```

I know it adds the numbers that you add to the command line, but why does "i" start with 2? I understand the for loop, so you don't have to go into detail about that.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: FWIW, calling it `argv` is a [convention inherited from C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3024197/201952), where it means *argument vector* (array).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Do a quick `console.log(process.argv)` and you'll immediately spot the problem.

It starts on 2 because `process.argv` contains the whole command-line invocation:

```
process.argv = ['node', 'yourscript.js', ...]
```

Elements `0` and `1` are not "arguments" from the script's point of view, but they are for the shell that invoked the script.

Comment: elements 0 and 1 are arguments to the shell. The rest are arguments to node.js.

Comment: @jonschlinkert No, 1 is for Node.

Answer (score 35):

It starts with 2 because the code will be run with

```
node myprogram.js firstarg secondarg
```

So

```
process.argv[0] == "node"

process.argv[1] == "myprogram.js"

process.argv[2] == "firstarg"
```

[Online docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Answer (score 7):

#### Your program prints the sum of the numerical values of the "command line arguments" provided to the node script.

For example:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/node ./sum-process-argv.js 1 2 3
6
```

From the [Node.js API documentation for `process.argv`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

> An array containing the command line arguments. The first element will be 'node', the second element will be the name of the JavaScript file. The next elements will be any additional command line arguments.

In the above examples those values are:

```
process.argv[0] == '/usr/local/bin/node'
process.argv[1] == '/Users/maerics/src/js/sum-process-argv.js'
process.argv[2] == '1'
process.argv[3] == '2'
process.argv[4] == '3'
```

See also the [`Number(...)` function/contructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is not about on how `process.argv` works -'cause there is a lot of answers here-, instead, it is on how you can get the values using [`array destructuring syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

For example, if you run your script with:

```
node app.js arthur 35
```

you can get those values *in a more readable* way like this:

```
const [node, script, name, age] = process.argv;

console.log(node); // node
console.log(script); // app.js
console.log(name); // arthur
console.log(age); // 35
```

You can omit the first and second *places* of your `process.argv`, and stay only with `name` and `age`:

```
const [, , name, age] = process.argv;
```

---

If you want all the arguments in an array, you can do it using the [`rest syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), that *collects multiple elements and condenses them into a single element* like this:

```
const [node, script, ...params] = process.argv;

console.log(node); // node
console.log(script); // app.js
console.log(params); // [ 'arthur', '35' ]
```

and of course, you can omit the first and second *places* of your `process.argv`, and stay only with your *params*:

```
const [, , ...params] = process.argv;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the node.js, the command line arguments are always stored in an array. In that array, the first element is the node command we refer to because we begin the command line with word “node”. The second element is the javascript (JS) file we refer to that often comes after the node command.

As we know, in the first element in JS array begins from zero, the second element is 1, and it goes 2, 3, 4 and on. Let’s name this array process.argv and add command line arguments x and y. Then, this is how we are going to call these elements:

```
var process.argv = ['node', 'file.js', ‘x’, ‘y’];
var process.argv [0] = node;
var process.argv [1]= file.js;
var process.argv[2] = x;
var process.argv[3] = y;
```

In short, element 0 and 1 are native to node.js, and we don't use them when we write any command line argument. That's why we ignore 0 and 1 and always begin from 2.

If we want to loop through the command line arguments, again we have to start from 2. Here is what we use for looping.

```
for (i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++){
console.log(process.argv[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute it like:

```
node code.js <argument> <argument>....
```

It take into account all command line invocation. For `process.argv[]` array will have `["node","code.js","<argument>",...]`
Because of that your arguments that in array start with index 2

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```js
const getHasCli = (prefix, alias = undefined) => {
  const prefixIndex = process.argv.findIndex(
    (arg) => arg === prefix || (alias && arg === alias)
  );
  return prefixIndex > 0;
};

const getCliData = (prefix, alias = undefined) => {
  let data = undefined;
  const prefixIndex = process.argv.findIndex(
    (arg) => arg === prefix || (alias && arg === alias)
  );
  if (prefixIndex > 0) {
    const cliData = process.argv[prefixIndex + 1] ?? undefined;
    if (cliData) {
      data = cliData.includes("-") ? undefined : cliData;
    }
  }
  return data;
};

(async () => {
  console.log(getCliData("--dir"));
  console.log(getCliData("--outDir"));
  console.log(getHasCli("--delete"));
  console.log(getHasCli("--ignore"));
})();
```

Example usage

```bash
node app.js --dir "./public" --delete
```

Return

```
./public
undefined
true
false
```

Comment: can use like this "console.log(getCliData("--dir", "-d"));" second param is alias.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that your question has been answered and, that your explanation describes some criteria this answer does not meet. However, your question's title seems to imply something other than the description.

I.e. `What does "argv" mean?` vs. `What's in "argv"?`.
I wanted to know the answer to the first question rather than the last and I hit this question due to the title's phrasing.

The answer, to: `What does "argv" mean?`, I found out, is due to NodeJS's V8-heritage.
The Javascript-engine V8 is written in C++ and in C++ the `main()` function (application entry-point) is most often written as:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Where:

`argc` is the amount of arguments supplied i.e. the argument-count and,

`argv` is a pointer to a "vector" i.e. the argument-vector.

NodeJS provides `process.argv` as an array so the `argc` used in the C++ main function can be replaced by `process.argv.length` and does not need to be provided.

To the best of my knowledge that's what `argv` "means" and where it "came from".
Hope this helps other curious souls out there.

Answer (score -4):

process.agrv[i]- basically loops through the command line arguments passed in the terminal while executing the file.
for example- If you run the file as
$ node prog.js 1 2 3 , then process.argv[0]=1 and so on..