# What's the JavaScript syntax after the require() call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, minimist

The following code is from the Node.js course I am following:

```
var args = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(2), { string: "name"});
```

I understand that a module is being imported, but I don't understand the second set of parentheses after the `require()` call:

```
require("minimist")(this part I don't understand)
```

Specifically, what is the second set of parentheses in terms of syntax?

I know how `slice()` works, and I understand that `string: "name"` creates a command line argument to check for, but what method is being called through the `require()` call, and how?

PS: The course (by Kyle Simpson) indicates that the above syntax will be explained later, but I haven't been able to locate the specific part, and I don't like to proceed without understanding something.  I am new to both JS and Node.js.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213980/could-someone-explain-what-process-argv-means-in-node-js-please

Comment: @ptts That link covers argv.  I know how argv is passed to the process.  My question concerns the syntax as I have explained in detail in my question (at least I thought I made myself clear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it looks like the module you are requiring is simply returning a function which you are immediately calling with `()` and passing in two arguments: `process.argv.slice(2)` and `{ string: "name"}`

So if your module looked like this:

```
// minimist.js
function test(str){
    console.log(str)
    return "Called with:" + str
}
module.exports = test;  // exports the function
```

you could use it like:

```
var arg = require('./minimist.js')("Hello") // calls the function minimist.js exported
```

Comment: OK, I understand your example.  Will accept as soon as SO lets me. Thank you.  Didn't know about module.exports, so thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to name each part to figure it out: Let's put it this way:

```
var args = tmp(v1, v2);
```

As you can see, that is clearly a **function calling**. Right?

And now, imagine that:

```
var tmp=require("minimist");
var v1=process.argv.slice(2);
var v2={ string: "name"};
```

Now you got it: `tmp` -namely the value returned by `slice()`- must be necessarily a **function** that accepts two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

[minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) is a package to parse command line arguments, and it exports a function.

`require('minimist')` will return a function like `function(args, opts={})`. Then you pass arguments to this function.

**First argument** - `process.argv.slice(2)`

`process.argv` is an array of parts of your command. For example if you type in your terminal

```
node app.js --test -x 1 --name '123'
```

Your `process.argv` will be an array

```
['node', 'app.js', '--test', '-x', 1, '--name', '123']
```

Here `['node', 'app.js']` is obvious you have to call. So to get your options you have to use `.slice(2)`, and it will be

```
['--test', '-x', 1, '--name', '123']
```

Now go to the next...

**Second argument** - `{ string: "name" }`

From minimist documentation you can find the following

> `opts.string` - a string or array of strings argument names to always treat as strings

It means your 'name' argument will be accepted as string. From example above:

```
name = '123' // not 123
```

Hope it's clear now for you. Comment if anything is not.

Comment: Thank you so much Rashad, Təşəkkür edirəm.  Really clear now.