# The point of using process.argv[2] while calling a function

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and the tutorial I am following always calls functions in the end using `JSONconvert(process.argv[2],process.argv[3])`, or just sometimes with `JSONconvert(process.argv[2])`. My question is what is the use of `process.arv[2]` because even if I run the code without it, it still works. If I do a `console.log` it prints undefined. For reference here is the `.js` code I am working on which converts a CSV to JSON.

```
const fs= require('fs');
const path=require('path');
const csv=require("csvtojson");
const csvFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'customer-data.csv')
const jsonFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'customer-data.json') 

const JSONconvert = () => {
    console.log('Converting from CSV file to JSON file ...')

    const converter = csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)

    converter.then((jsonObj) => {
        fs.writeFileSync(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2))
    })

    converter.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(`error: ${error}`)
        process.exit(1)
    })

    converter.on('done', () => {
        console.log('Successfully converted at', jsonFilePath)
    })
}

JSONconvert(process.argv[2],process.argv[3]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could someone explain what "process.argv" means in node.js please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213980/could-someone-explain-what-process-argv-means-in-node-js-please)

Answer (score 0):

The full command line for calling a node script is `node script arg1 arg2 ...`.  These elements are held in the array `process.argv`.  Element 0 is always node, 1 is always your script name, everything afterwards are arguments supplied on the command line.  If you supply none they will be undefined.

For more information:

- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_argv
- https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/