# when I run my `node file.js 1 23 44` script, it doesn't prinout anything

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run `node file.js 1 23 45`, it's supposed to printout `One TwoThree FourFive` but for some reason it's not printing out. I think the script runs fine because I get no issues running it but it just doesn't printout anything. Am I missing something or am I completely wrong?

```js
const numbersMap = new Map([
    [ "0", "Zero" ],
    [ "1", "One"],
    [ "2", "Two"],
    [ "3", "Three"],
    [ "4", "Four"],
    [ "5", "Five"],
    [ "6", "Six"],
    [ "7", "Seven"],
    [ "8", "Eight"],
    [ "9", "Nine"]
  ]); 
  
 

  function toDigits (integers) {
    const r = [];
  
    for (const n of integers) {
      const stringified = n.toString(10);
      let name = "";
  
      for (const digit of stringified)
        name += numbersMap.get(digit);
      r.push(name);
    }
  
    console.log(r.join());
  }
```

Comment: `toDigits` is not being called?

Comment: how would I do that?@evolutionxbox

Comment: You can call the function using `toDigits()`. If you want to pass the arguments in, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213980/could-someone-explain-what-process-argv-means-in-node-js-please

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did try it before but I get `integers is not iterable`

Comment: May you share that example? We can't debug code that's invisible

Comment: ` for (const n of integers) {
                    ^

TypeError: integers is not iterable `
@evolutionxbox

Comment: How is `integers` being defined?

Comment: `TypeError: integers is not iterable
    at toDigits 
    at Object.<anonymous> `
@evolutionxbox

Comment: Sorry @qTips that error just says that it doesn't exist. Are you defining it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You defined the Map and the method `toDigits`, but are not actually calling the method. You can do that by adding `toDigits(...)`.
To parse the command line arguments you can use `process.argv`. This will give you something like

```js
[
  'node',
  '/path/to/script/index.js',
  '1',
  '23',
  '45'
]
```

Which you can use e.g., with `process.argv.slice(2)`in your code.

```js
const numbersMap = new Map([
  [ "0", "Zero" ],
  [ "1", "One"],
  [ "2", "Two"],
  [ "3", "Three"],
  [ "4", "Four"],
  [ "5", "Five"],
  [ "6", "Six"],
  [ "7", "Seven"],
  [ "8", "Eight"],
  [ "9", "Nine"]
]);

function toDigits (integers) {
  const r = [];

  for (const n of integers) {
    const stringified = n.toString(10);
    let name = "";

    for (const digit of stringified)
      name += numbersMap.get(digit);
    r.push(name);
  }

  console.log(r.join());
}

// You can parse command line arguments like this:
const integers = process.argv.slice(2);

// and then pass them on
toDigits(integers);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question? _"when I run my `node file.js 1 23 44` script, it doesn't print out anything"_

Comment: You're right. Updated the answer with a short example on how to parse the command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: I think this might be the solution @SebastianRichner, @evolutionxbox. I used the `process.argv.slice(2)` before but from what I know the input are strings and not integers, so now  my question is, are the arugments in `node file.js 1 23 44`, still integers?

Comment: @qTips they're strings. Do you need them to be numbers? Looking at this answer I don't think you do

Comment: They're strings. So you can safely remove the `n.toString(10)` line. (Or leave it, as string.toString() will still simply return a string.)

Comment: @SebastianRichner @evolutionxbox, my problem is am supposed to convert an array of integers into an array of strings representing the phonetic equivalent of the
integer. This is why am using the `toString()` function.

Comment: Using the command line `node file.js 1 23 44` the "numbers" are strings. So there's no need to convert them.

Comment: the only thing that worries me is that input needs to be integers, because if they are strings already than am not technically converting the array of integers into an array of strings. @evolutionxbox

Comment: What is the question that's being asked? Does it specify a command line input?

Comment: `Convert an array of integers into an array of strings representing the phonetic equivalent of the integer.` this is the question, @evolutionxbox

Comment: `Given an array: [3, 25, 209], print “Three,TwoFive,TwoZeroNine” into stdout.` 
this is the example they gave me @evolutionxbox

Comment: Command line arguments will always be passed as strings. The question does not specify that the integers need to come from the command line. @qTips can you specify what is missing in the answer?

Comment: @SebastianRichner, the only thing I know is that they will run my code like this `node nameOfFile.js 1 33 400`. Thats why am so confuse about the question because I don't know where the array of integers are coming from.

Comment: If that is the case, then the code from the answer will print the expected output and you can remove the `toString()` part.

Comment: @SebastianRichner, how do you interpret this question, or what would you go about this?

Comment: If they will run your code like you've mentioned, then you can safely assume that this does what is asked in the question, since it does print the words as expected.

Comment: @qTips, Please consider accepting this answer, if it was helpful.